# Why did the Engineer sleep for 2000 years?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In Prometheus, we saw that the last Engineer on LV-223 slept for 2000 years until humans came. Why did he sleep for 2000 years? Why didn't he go to "Paradise" immediately?

Comment: Probably some form of the Y2K bug caused the sleep pod to malfunction.

Comment: "Lets sleep and forgot all what happened"

Comment: I asked this question myself...it seems very odd, a GLITCH in the story and Ridley Scott's direction. Who knows, maybe we will find out in the next installment along with a lot of other things. But 2000 years?....I think he would've been a little more sick and disoriented than what he was, no matter what the species. But I tend to agree with the answer before me...he was already in stasis set to be woke up at a certain time, or maybe he was the designated jockey and the others were the navigators and so forth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My impression from the movie was that he'd entered the pod in some haste, and probably had set it to sleep indefinitely, in the hopes that someone else would wake him once the outbreak was dealt with.

He was correct in this hope, though not in the way that he'd expected.

Comment: This reminds me that hologram records that David watched alone. There was three Engeeners there, but we see only one Engeener at end. Those three Engeeners were looking very calm.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding was that the Engineer was either *already* in stasis *prior* to his crew-mates being infected and was set to be woken up when the ship reached Earth, or alternatively, placed himself in stasis to avoid infection. I prefer the former explanation as, upon waking up, he does not really show any interest in the bio-weapon's present status.